# Multiple Rank in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table with following columns:

This is my table: `test`

```
ID    UID    TAG    Name    Points
1     1      1      asd     10
2     2      2      qwe     30
3     2      1      zxc     20
4     2      2      rty     20
5     3      1      fgh     40
```

I need to get the name from the table which is related to a particular user (UID) which I provide externally. And for all the names, rank should be given along with name depending on the tag.

For example, with a select query as:

`SELECT name, ... as rank from test ... where UID=2 ...`

I should get the result as:

```
Name   Rank
zxc    2
qwe    1
rty    2
```

Explanation:

Here `zxc` is related to `UID=2` and is 2nd in Rank in `TAG=1`, thus it is second.

Similarly for `qwe` is related to `UID=2` and is 1st in Rank in `TAG=2`, thus it is first.

I hope anyone can help me to formulate a select query for this.

Comment: Your sample data has a Points column, but your query uses rank. Same column?

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: How the rank should depend on the tag? can you explain?

Comment: `UID` is the main cluster here, where there can be different `TAG`. For each tag, the ranking is different. For `tag=1` there will be 1 to n rank, and so on for `tag=2` and so.

Comment: @asterisk  SO is not a service where you ask query ... You have to show an effort and use the answers to think... You do not deserve my answer

Comment: @etsa, I am sorry if you felt wrong. I already got the answer. Your's was a different one, so I thought in future maybe someone would appreciate an answer like yours, so I just was trying to fine tune yours, as I don't have much reputation to edit directly. Anyways, if you felt bad, I am really sorry.

Comment: @asterisk  be sure: I do not feel bad for your cause, you are not so important.  I think you should think about what I wrote and comunicate better.   ORDER was irrelevant for question.

Comment: @etsa I am not so important and that is the reason why you down voted a good question. I accepted my mistake and apologised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the rank on basis of tag and points you can use something like below

```
select t.*,
( select count(*)
  from test tt
  where t.TAG = tt.TAG
 AND t.Points <= tt.Points
) `rank`
from test t
where t.UID = 2
order by t.TAG
```

In above query the subquery part will get the count of records by comparing same table where tag is same and points of first reference table t is less or equal to points of second reference table tt, so for row uid => 2 tag=> 2 name=> qwe & points => 30 is compared with same row & all other rows it will return count of 1. same case for row uid => 2 tag=> 2 name=> rty & points => 20 when this row is compared with first row,with itself and all other rows it will return a count of 2 and so on for remaining rows, thus we can use these counts as a rank which is actually a rank

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7fbff/7)

Edit for rank no. issue

```
select t.*,
( select count(*)
  from test tt
  where t.TAG = tt.TAG
 AND t.Points < tt.Points
) +1 `rank`
from test t
where t.UID = 2
order by t.TAG
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8695ea/3)

Comment: Thank You so much :) Explanation for future readers will be great :)

Comment: I was just testing the system and found out that, consider if three people `a` , `b` and `c` of the same tag value and have points as `20`, `10` and `10`. Then `a` will have a rank `1` and `b` and `c` will have a rank `3`. There is no `2`. Can you modify to add a check of the `ID` when a case like this happen to rank them `2` and `3`?

Comment: @asterisk i have updated my query removed the equals part which was cause this issue because for same points it also counts the another element which increases the rank count

Answer (score 1):

Variable `@rank` gets incremented by 1 for each set of values thus keeping the same value for duplicates.

**Query**

```
set @rank := 0; 
set @points := ''; 
select @rank := case when @points = Points then @rank else @rank + 1 end as rank, name,
@points := Points as Points
from your_table_name
where UID = 2
order by UID, Points desc;
```

Comment: Just add `name` to the `select`. I have updated my answer.

Comment: The tags are getting mixed up. first `tag=1` is shown, then `tag=2` and then again `tag=1` depending on the points I think.

Comment: your answer is useful when a person wants to sort his results with points. So +1 for that.